# migrate a struts 1 app from weblogic 8 to weblogic 10

Tags: war, upgrade, struts-1, weblogic-10.x, weblogic8.x

I have an Struts 1.1 application which is running on Weblogic 8.1
I want to upgrade this application to weblogic 10.3.0.

Can anyone suggest me a proper way to upgrade the application ?? Any input is welcome on this.

Comment: it will depend on how many wls 8.1 classes you are using in that application. There are authentication, webservices, etc. wls classes that can be used.

Try deploying it straighforward and see what happens. A good way to identify any differences.

Comment: Please tell me the steps to import it weblogic 10.3.0 workspace

Comment: do you mean domain ? or eclipse workspace ?

Comment: not eclipse...i m talking about the workspace provided with weblogic